# custom event not caught in HTML Vuejs

Tags: event-handling, vuejs2

I have an HTML partial like:

```
<div v-on:customevent="test">
   <button @click="launchEvent">TestEvent</button>
</div>
```

In my component I have this:

```
methods:{
   launchEvent(){
      this.$emit('customevent');
   },
   test(){
      console.log("I'm in");   
   }
}
```

But even tt runs correctly function `launchEvent` it doesn't launch function test as the event was not caught because the event is correctly launched because if I try set in created():

```
this.$on('customevent',function(){
   alert("customevent launched");
});
```

The alert is correctly launched, so, Is it possible listen custom event directly on HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited after OP pointed that the answer wasn't working*

Those events are meant to be used in a parent-child component relationship, as explained in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components)

So, in your example, you should have a parent component catching the event and the child component emitting it.

Your parent will looks like :

```
<parent @custom-event="customEventCatched">
  <child></child>
<parent>
```

And your child component's template should be like :

```
<button @click="$emit('custom-event')">Emit<button>
```

Comment: thankyou! I tried but it doesn't work. I edit my question with your advise

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dangvanthanh/3m6s54qx/ following this jsfiddle I found problem

Comment: My bad, I forgot to say that those events are meant to notify a parent component, I'm updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect in the first div, 'clicked' should be 'click', as in

```
<div v-on:click="test">Test Event</div>
```

or the short-hand syntax as used on the button,

```
<div @click="test">Test Event</div>
```

Comment: hello thank you, not, the name is exactly clicked, because i need a CUSTOM events, it could be named "customevent", but i would listen a custom event, not click event. I edit my answer for more clarity

Comment: $emit events is usually for communicating to the parent, but in case there's another reason to catch it in the same component, try defining the method with `onTest:function() {...}`

Comment: yes, following this jsFiddle I found the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/dangvanthanh/3m6s54qx/

Comment: Could you post your fixed code in an answer please?

Comment: yes I answered my question my problem was a $emit, it was wrong because at first I had used a bus general, and the parent/child component. thankyou for your advise

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I not use correctly event:

now my code is:

```
<div>
   <MyComponent @customevent="eventCatched"></MyComponent>
</div>
```

And in **MyComponent** there is a function like:

```
test(){
   this.$emit("customevent");
}
```

In parent component I have a function **eventCatched**

```
eventCatched(){
  console.log("catched");
}
```

following this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dangvanthanh/3m6s54qx/